# Apache2.2 mod_rewrite map function based on POST variables

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Are POST variables accessible to mod_rewrite?
 I am trying to determine whether or not it is possible to perform a redirect with Apache2.2 and mod_rewrite
where the rewrite rule considers the POST variables associated with a request, and uses these values to inform 
the final destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

One of the reasons we have HTTP-POST is to keep application data out of the URL. So using something that by its definition reformats URLs to try to access that data won't work.

mod_rewrite is for turning

www.foo.com/index.php?uglyparameter=bar

into

www.foo.com/bar

So the user doesn't have to hurt their eyes on an ugly URL. Other uses here: 
[Apache Mod Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html)

Comment: thanks.  im actually trying to make a high level decision about where to send the request, based on the content of the post data, but i guess this is not the way to do it.

Comment: If you have your heart set on routing traffic based on form input, you can use javascript to change the client-side form elements action property on submit.  I recommend against this, as it goes against what I mentioned in my first answer.  It just makes the most sense to handle an HTTP POST request on the server.